# What are the implications of running multiple commands in one ANSI escape sequence?

Tags: colors, ansi-escape

I have seen online that people sometimes string together ANSI escape sequences, yet on the [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) they don't do it even once.

Thus, my concern is that stringing multiple commands together might not be as widely supported as single commands, so I would like confirmation whether this is a valid and safe way to do it. My other concern is performance-related, and I wonder if one version might be faster?

---

Example:

For instance, one might want to string an 8-bit foreground and background color.
Classic way: `\033[38;5;22m` `\033[48;5;65m`
All together: `\033[38;5;22;48;5;65m`

Comment: These escape sequences have a very specific format. Deviating from it will likely not work as you intended. With that said, some escape sequences *do* allow it. Does this sequence allow it? Maybe. And will depend a *lot* on the terminal you will write them to, if they support it or not. So the best bet, if you want to be portable, is to separate the commands. You can still have multiple commands in a single string so I don't really see the big deal.

Comment: [ECMA-48](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-48_5th_edition_june_1991.pdf) says “If the number of parameters is variable, neither the maximum number of values nor the order in which the corresponding actions are performed are defined by this Standard” (5.4.3), and, for the `m` command to set colors and other graphic rendition parameters, “The usable combinations of parameter values are determined by the implementation” (8.3.117). This standard does not cover the parameters 38 and 48 for `m`, so I presume they are covered by some other document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSI-`m` escape sequence is a special case (along with mode setting sequences CSI-`h`, CSI-`?h`, CSI-`l`, CSI-`?l` and media copy CSI-`i`, CSI-`?i`) that can combine multiple attribute modifications as consecutive arguments or even groups of arguments.

You can indeed combine `\033[38;5;22m\033[48;5;65m` as `\033[38;5;22;48;5;65m` to set both the foreground and the background as extended colors.

Be aware of these limitations:

- it makes the code less readable
- there is a limit to the number of arguments supported by CSI-`m` which may differ from one terminal to another (I use 16 in QuickEmacs terminal emulator, I am not sure if there is mandatory value).
- the performance difference in insignificant given today's connection throughputs especially when running programs locally.

For these reasons, I would not recommend combining these sequences.

Comment: What document specifies this?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: the Wikipedia page [ANSI_escape_code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) in reference seems quite well documented and mentions many sources.  I wish I had used it many years ago to write the emulator :)

Comment: I was inquiring about an authoritative source.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: this standard is not recent, [ECMA-48](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-48/) seems to be the authoritative source. [ECMA-48 2nd edition August 1979](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-48_2nd_edition_august_1979.pdf) or the more recent [5th edition](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-48_2nd_edition_august_1979.pdf) but many vendor extensions are implemented in terminal emulators.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing an escape character and bracket by a semicolon on just color sequences would be an ***insignificant*** difference in speed.  Most of the characters sent (unless you're working on some ASCII screensaver) are not *color*, but *text*.

As noted in comments, ECMA-48 is the relevant standard, but in turn it does not specify what happens for *SGR* codes 38 and 48.  The XTerm FAQ [*Can I set a color by its number?*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#color_by_number) goes into some detail explaining the various code-encodings, including the origin of the 38/48 as shown in the example:

> (reserved for future standardization; intended for setting character foreground colour as specified in ISO 8613-6 [CCITT Recommendation T.416])

At the time, that T.416 was not readily available for clarification.  Later, someone noticed that (comparing ECMA-48 and T.416) the parameters following 38/48 should have been the colon (<kbd>`:`</kbd>) character rather than semicolon (<kbd>`;`</kbd>).  xterm has for several years accepted either form, some other terminals recognize only the semicolon form which their developers copied from xterm.

Besides *SGR*, other commands may be combined, but that depends on the terminal implementation.  For instance, the (hardware) VT100 accepted a sequence of cursor movements (repeated up, down, left or right) using its optional parameters.  For instance, rather than just one parameter in the cursor-up, one could have a series of parameters (letting the terminal add them up).

Few terminal emulators implement this feature.

But (probably) all terminal emulators have a limit on the number of parameters which they would recognize in a control sequence.  That is because the type of control sequence is not known until it ends.  For *SGR*, the final character is **`m`**, while for cursor addressing it is **`H`**.  Even though cursor-addressing accepts only two parameters, the parser has to keep track (up to its limit) to determine if that is *SGR* or a malformed cursor address.